# Selenium 2: Unable to set PROXY for Internet Explorer

Tags: java, selenium

I want to set proxy and open IE (version 9, selenium 2.25) but this is not working for IE, though it is working for Firefox.

Here is my code:

```
String PROXY  = "somehost.com" + ":" + "80";
     org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
        proxy.setHttpProxy(PROXY);
        proxy.setFtpProxy(PROXY);
        proxy.setSslProxy(PROXY);
        
     DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer(); 
     ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
     ieCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
      WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities); 
      driver.get("http://www.cnn.com/");
```

Following run time error occurred:

> Aug 16, 2012 2:00:13 PM org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.WindowsProxyManager backupRegistrySettings
>
> INFO: Backing up registry settings...

Answer (score 0):

The message you get is just right - it is no exception (but an informational message). To use IE via Selenium, some specific settings will be changed in the Registry (only for Selenium runs, BTW - and the registry will be restored afterwards).

Do you have the rights to change your registry (check if you can run regedit)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually following code produces more errors: